# reparsing a logstash record? fix extracts?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, amazon-cloudtrail

I'm taking a JSON message ([Cloudtrail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/event_reference_top_level.html), many objects concatenated together) and by the time I'm done filtering it, Logstash doesn't seem to be parsing the message correctly. It's as if the hash was simply dumped into a string.

Anyhow, here's the input and filter.

```
input {
  s3 {
    bucket => "stanson-ops"
    delete => false
    #snipped unimportant bits
    type => "cloudtrail"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "cloudtrail" {
    json { # http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/json
      source => "message"
    }
    ruby {
      code => "event['RecordStr'] = event['Records'].join('~~~')"
    }
    split {
      field => "RecordStr"
      terminator => "~~~"
      remove_field => [ "message", "Records" ]
    }
  }
}
```

By the time I'm done, elasticsearch entries include a `RecordStr` key with the following data. It doesn't have a `message` field, nor does it have a `Records` field.

```
{"eventVersion"=>"1.01", "userIdentity"=>{"type"=>"IAMUser", "principalId"=>"xxx"}}
```

Note that is **not** JSON style, it's been parsed. (which is important for the concat->split thing to work).

So, the `RecordStr` key looks not quite right as one value. Further, in Kibana, filterable fields include `RecordStr` (no subfields). It includes some entries that aren't there anymore: `Records.eventVersion`, `Records.userIdentity.type`.

Why is that? How can I get the proper fields?

**edit 1** here's part of the input.

```
{"Records":[{"eventVersion":"1.01","userIdentity":{"type":"IAMUser",
```

It's unprettified JSON. It appears the body of the file (the above) is in the `message` field, `json` extracts it and I end up with an array of records in the `Records` field. That's why I join and split it- I then end up with individual documents, each with a single `RecordStr` entry. However, the template(?) doesn't seem to understand the new structure.

Comment: What does the input data look like?

Comment: @MagnusBäck [see this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/event_reference_top_level.html), which gives a readable example.

Comment: Does that example exactly represent what the log looks like, or has the JSON been pretty-printed? I'm asking since there's no way that your configuration would be able to parse that example. Perhaps the [cloudtrail codec](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/codecs/cloudtrail) would be useful?

Comment: @MagnusBäck I added the first hundred characters or so. Let me know if more is needed, but it appears to line up- I've placed an explanation too. The cloudtrail codec [doesn't exist on github](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/tree/1.4/lib/logstash/codecs)- I don't know why there is a document for it.

Comment: As the documentation says, it's part of the contrib plugin package which is found in a git of its own. See the [installation instructions](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/contrib-plugins).

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out a method that allows for indexing the appropriate CloudTrail fields as you requested. Here are the modified input and filter configs:

```
input {
  s3 {
    backup_add_prefix => \"processed-logs/\"
    backup_to_bucket => \"test-bucket\"
    bucket => \"test-bucket\"
    delete => true
    interval => 30
    prefix => \"AWSLogs/<account-id>/CloudTrail/\"
    type => \"cloudtrail\"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == \"cloudtrail\" {
    json {
      source => \"message\"
    }
    ruby {
      code => \"event.set('RecordStr', event.get('Records').join('~~~'))\"
    }
    split {
      field => \"RecordStr\"
      terminator => \"~~~\"
      remove_field => [ \"message\", \"Records\" ]
    }
    mutate {
      gsub => [
        \"RecordStr\", \"=>\", \":\"
      ]
    }
    mutate {
      gsub => [
        \"RecordStr\", \"nil\", \"null\"
      ]
    }
    json {
      skip_on_invalid_json => true
      source => \"RecordStr\"
      target => \"cloudtrail\"
    }
    mutate {
      add_tag => [\"cloudtrail\"]
      remove_field=>[\"RecordStr\", \"@version\"]
    }
    date {
      match => [\"[cloudtrail][eventTime]\",\"ISO8601\"]
    }
  }
}
```

The key observation here is that once the split is done we no longer possess valid json in the event and are therefore required to execute the mutate replacements ('=>' to ':' and 'nil' to 'null'). Additionally, I found it useful to get the timestamp out of the CloudTrail eventTime and do some cleanup of unnecessary fields.